# Using Calendar Cocoapods in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I would like to use one of these two cocoapods, https://github.com/graycampbell/GCCalendar, and https://github.com/n8armstrong/CalendarView

I installed with `pod install` that went great. But when it comes to implementation I don't get it.

For **GCCalendar** it says "Create a subclass of GCCalendarViewController" and when I do that my Xcode turns red from errors. **CalendarView** docs say to use `@IBOutlet weak var calendar: CalendarView!` but when I do that I get errors. `CalendarView!` doesn't exist.

Can somebody explain what should I do to use CalendarView (I like this more). What should I do first in Xcode after installing pods?

Here is what I get:

[image]

Comment: I recomend you to use https://github.com/n8armstrong/CalendarView, I look quickly and I see it very easy to use. First you need to import CalendarView to  YourViewController.swift file, and you have to initialize CalendarView to your ViewController like so:          let calendar = CalendarView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(view.frame), 320))
view.addSubview(calendar)

Comment: Yeah, I like this more and I want to use it but I guess I'm missing something big here because whatever I do I get errors.

Answer (score 1):

Sometime Xcode can not see your pod after you install it in Swift. : (

You can fix issue by press `Cmd+B` for Build Project after you install Pod.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to import your library above your ViewController, so Xcode doesn't understand  `CalendarView`

let import it:

```
import CalendarView
```

then build project to notify Xcode understand that you have just imported it :).

then initialize `CalendarView` inside your ViewController with it's frame, like so:

```
let calendar = CalendarView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(view.frame), 320))
view.addSubview(calendar)
```

if you want to use `@IBOutlet weak var calendar: CalendarView!`

You need to drag a UIView to your storyboard, then set it's class is `CalendarView`, then reference it to your IBOutlet. Hope this help you.

Comment: I tried to do that and it says:  cannot load underlying module for 'CalendarView'

Comment: Have you imported CalendarView, then build your project yet?

Comment: Yes. No luck. I got another one: error: /blah/Debug-iphonesimulator/CalendarView/CalendarView.bundle: No such file or directory

Comment: @khuong291 I think you shouldn't leave your Skype ID here if you want to avoid being spammed later... :) If you want to chat with OP you can open a chatroom on SO with them.

Comment: I just want to help him easier :), ok, I will delete that comment :)

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve this on my own. I'll post an answer in case somebody else sucks here.

In my case, `CalendarView.bundle` was not present in `.../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CalendarView/`

So I `cp -r` from `/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/yourapp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CalendarView/CalendarView/CalendarView.bundle`

This works.